# JQuery: Select Elements changes tracked but not their values!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just got a questioned answered and have fallen into another trap!

I have a form which is in a [lightbox](http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js) and I want to track every change in the select elements. When they change I want to get the value of each of the select elements. I have tried to do the following:

```
$('select.htt, select.hst').live('change', function() {
    var channels = parseInt($('select.hst').val(), 10) * parseInt($('select.htt').val(), 10);
    alert($('select.hst').val() + ' and ' + $('select.htt').val());         
    $('span.yellow2').html(channels);
});
```

However, the values are always the same i.e. the first option in each drop down box even though there are other options selected. I am guessing like somebody has explained before. The lightbox I am using takes a copy of these elements and makes changes to them and JQuery can not see this, but I have been told to reference the elements via classes which has worked but only up to this point.

What else can I try and what is the problem?

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that you have two (or more) copies of your `select` elements. When you call `$('select.hst').val()`, jQuery returns the value of the first `select` element with class `hst` that it finds, which is not the value you want.

You will have to find a way to scope your jQuery selectors to **only the elements inside the visible lightbox div**. If the lightbox div has an id or some other unique attribute, use that to scope your form/select/span elements.

If the lightbox div has id "lightbox":

```
<div id="lightbox">
...
</div>
```

Use selectors of the form:

```
$('#lightbox select.hst').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things (try the first then then the first + second):

You are choosing select, not option, so try choosing all options that are selected

```
   $('select.hst option:selected').val()
```

Second, you are choosing `val()` which will return the value attribute of the option. Just in case you want the text instead, choose `text()`.